# MYSQL storing input values in one row or multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working with PHP and MySQL, and I'm not too experienced with database design. I know the basics of normalization, however my question is about storing vales from a specific form I have.

Ok, so the way my page in question is set up, there are text boxes that can be dynamically added or removed. If the user presses a "+" or "-" button it adds or removes another text box.

Anyway, when I pull the text box values via $_POST it is an array, and then I convert it to a string using implode() Ex: user enters "hello" "world" "bye" "world", implode converts it to the following string "hello,world,bye,world".

My question is would it be better to store this string "hello,world,bye,world" in 1 row as 1 entry, or would it be better to break this string into 4 separate strings and store it in 4 different rows?  Each text box will contain questions/comments so they could be potentially long and most likely not 1 word like the example I gave.

The reason why I'm asking this is because all of these inputs will be used on the same page, so they can all share a unique ID. Instead of querying multiple times, I'd only have to query once.

Comment: What happens if someone enters a comma in one of the fields?

Comment: Hmm, very true. I could always use a "~" or some rarely used character (and restrict the usage of it) but I'll just stick with the separate row method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be stored separately, because they're separate examples of one kind of data.

Your table would be (for example) `comments`, and each row should be one comment, so one row for `hello`, one for `world`, etc.

You could also store a page ID alongside the comments, so your table would look like this (note that you'd typically have an `id` field for comment id, as well. I've omitted it for brevity):

```
|--------------|---------|
| comment      | page_id |
|--------------|---------|
| hello        | 1       |
| world        | 1       |
| bye          | 2       |
|--------------|---------|
```

Then you can still search on page_id, but your data is logically separated, and you can search on the specific comments if you wish.

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE page_id = 1 -- 2 results
```

You can also do things like ordering it alphabetically, or by time (with a new column for that) very easily.

```
|--------------|---------|------------|
| comment      | page_id | time_made  |
|--------------|---------|------------|
| hello        | 1       | 1234567890 |
| world        | 1       | 2356480546 |
| bye          | 2       | 5168161543 |
|--------------|---------|------------|

SELECT * FROM comments WHERE page_id = 1 ORDER BY time_made DESC -- most recent first
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the examples. I'm going to store an ID beside them so I can reference it to that page like you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

it will be better to break this string into 4 separate strings and store it in 4 different rows in separate child  table.